# Downloading the content of a page stretched in Angular through BrowserKit

Tags: angular, symfony, download

I have a question about the BrowserKit library for Symfony. Is there any way to download the entire content of the page that is written on Angular? In order for the DOM tree to be completed so that I can parasite it with the help of DomCrawler, Angular's scripts must be executed, i.e. there is a need for JavaScript. Is there any way that will make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

BrowserKit can’t to execute JavaScript. You need to use something like Selenium, phantomJS, facebook’s webdriver.